# what type of languages i can learn for big data and hadoop

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I want to learn Hadoop and big data. I know core java concepts are enough like classes,objects,polymorphism,Abstract classes,exception handling and multithreading and applets? And i have another doubt. what type of data base i can learn for hadoop and big data? i have no idea of database.And what IDE i can download.please guide me any body.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is a very good start for big data as most of the technologies revolve around Hadoop and are written in Java.

Some use Python too but often Python has only second-class support.

Scala is another language that has a lot of big data libraries. For example [Twitter has a lot of big data technologies written in Scala](http://twitter.github.io/).

It really depends on what you want to do. As I said, Java is a good start. You can try to implement simple MapReduce "hello-worlds" such as [word counting](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Example%3a+WordCount+v1.0) and then quickly move to learn libraries and languages such as [Cascading](http://www.cascading.org/) and [Pig](https://pig.apache.org/). The reason is that your productivity will be likely higher in such higher-level languages. The resulting jobs might not be as efficient as hand-crafted mapreduce code but you can worry  about that later.

Comment: For Hadoop you don't need to know Spring, Struts or Hibernate. Even JDBC you don't usually need. Start with e.g. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Example%3A+WordCount+v1.0

Comment: Spring is (mostly) about building web apps, the same with Struts. Hibernate and JBoss you need mostly for enterprise software. For Big Data processing they are not a requirement.

Comment: Well, the point of Hadoop and "big data" is to complement traditional relational databases. So on the one hand you don't need to know any specific database but you have to know the concepts. That is, core Java is a good start but you also should know the theory of relational databases, why it is that there's such a thing as NoSQL databases, you should know a thing or two about database implementation (B-trees, indexes, ...), you should know algorithms (sorting, searching, ...).

Comment: And please edit your question to add the additional questions so that we can remove these comments.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting with the basics. Download the free sandboxes that HortonWorks or Cloudera provide. Both of these companies provide intro's to Hadoop and free tutorials which dive into the Hadoop tools (i.e., Pig, Hive, etc). From there I would recommend experimenting with interacting with Hadoop using Java since you are already familiar with that as a language.